# if the previous value on one column is bigger than the next value in another column, make it equal to the value in corresponding column

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a df like this

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), admi = c(50, 51, 
54, 93, 57, 160, 309, 321), dis = c(51, 127, 57, 94, 150, 410, 
313, 322)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

and I want the values to be in an increasing order like this

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), admi2 = c(50, 
51, 54, 93, 57, 160, 309, 321), dis2 = c(51, 51.5, 57, 94, 150, 
160.5, 313, 322)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

Basically, If the previous value for an ID in the dis column is bigger than the next value in the adm column, make that dis value equal to the value in the admission column and add 0.5 to it. Thank you
I tried using the code below

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(dplyr::across(c(dis, admi))) %>% 
  mutate(dis = ifelse(dis > lead(admi, default = first(admi)), admi + 0.5, dis))
```

which worked but it also for some reasons, change the last value in the dis column for each id where the condition is not even true.
it gave me this result

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), admi = c(50, 51, 
54, 93, 57, 160, 309, 321), dis = c(51, 51.5, 57, 93.5, 150, 
160.5, 313, 321.5)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), groups = structure(list(
    id = c(1, 2), .rows = structure(list(1:4, 5:8), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of `missing` argument in `if_else` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(dis = if_else(dis > lead(admi), admi + 0.5, dis, missing = dis)) %>%
  ungroup

#     id  admi   dis
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    50  51  
#2     1    51  51.5
#3     1    54  57  
#4     1    93  94  
#5     2    57 150  
#6     2   160 160. 
#7     2   309 313  
#8     2   321 322
```